# Bit Operations, mainly ~

Tags: c++

I am currently converting decimal to binary, making sure it is 8 bits. All bit operations work except the ~ (NOT) operations. They come out as a huge integer value. I am not sure why, since the other bit operations work. Here is my code: (The commented out lines are what is not working)

Edit: If I want to get 8 bit binary strings, what do I do? Use unsigned chars? If I change all unsigned ints to unsigned chars then my BinaryToDecimal function produces incorrect binary conversion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string BinaryToDecimal(unsigned int dec)
{
    string binary   = "";
    float remainder = 0.0f;

    while( dec != 0 )
    {
        remainder = dec % 2;
        dec      /= 2;

        if( remainder == 0 )
            binary.append("0");
        else
            binary.append("1");
    }


    // Reverse binary string
    string ret = string(binary.rbegin(), binary.rend());

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 0;
    unsigned int b = 0;

    cout << "Enter a number to convert to binary: ";
    cin  >> a;
    cout << "Enter a number to convert to binary: ";
    cin  >> b;

    cout << "A = " << BinaryToDecimal(a) << endl;
    cout << "B = " << BinaryToDecimal(b) << endl;

    unsigned int c = a & b;
    unsigned int d = a | b;
    //unsigned int e = ~a;
    //unsigned int f = ~b;
    unsigned int g = a ^ b;
    unsigned int h = a << 2;
    unsigned int i = b >> 3;

    cout << "A & B  = " << BinaryToDecimal(c) << endl;
    cout << "A | B  = " << BinaryToDecimal(d) << endl;
    //cout << "~A     = " << BinaryToDecimal(e) << endl;
    //cout << "~B     = " << BinaryToDecimal(f) << endl;
    cout << "A ^ B  = " << BinaryToDecimal(g) << endl;
    cout << "A << 2 = " << BinaryToDecimal(h) << endl;
    cout << "B >> 3 = " << BinaryToDecimal(i) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an `unsigned int` for the operations, such that the inversion of small number becomes a large number because of leading 1 starting from the MSB. If you only want the representation is 8 bit only, you should use `unsigned char` for its storage.
But you cannot change a or b to `unsigned char`. Otherwise, `cin >> a` will put the number's ASCII code to `a`, not a number. For example, your input is 5, it puts 0x35 ('5'), not number 5.

If you don't want to change `unsigned int` of your code, you can do some minor enhancements

```
string BinaryToDecimal(unsigned int dec)
{
    string binary   = "";
    float remainder = 0.0f;

    dec &= 0xff;        // only 8 bits you care about
    while( dec != 0 )
    {
        ....
```

But you are using `while( dec !=0 )`, which is buggy. If the result is already 0, then the function returns an empty string, not "0000". Instead, you should use a counter to count only for 8 bit.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
        if ((dec & 1) != 0)
            binary.append("1");
        else
            binary.append("0");
        dec >>= 1;
    }
```

Also, using bit wise `AND` to test the bit is 0 or 1, and shift operation, is better than / and % operators.

Finally, for 8 bit 5 (0000_0101), its inversion is 250 (1111_1010), not 1010.

Comment: Can you explain how the enhanced code works? For example what does dec&= 0xff; do?

Also the dec & 1 != 0, and dec >>= 1.

And if I wanted to use unsigned char, unsigned char c = A & B, what would I have to do in order to get that working?

Comment: `dec &= 0xff` will only keep low 8 bits. Other leading 1s will be eliminated, such that your `while(dec != 0)` won't produce a long sequence of string. `dec & 1` check the LSB is 0 or 1 by doing bitwise `AND` operation; `dec >>= 1` will do right shifting, for example, `0101` becomes `0010`.

Comment: Can you give an example of dec & 1? Like it's comparing say 5 & 1, is that comparing 0101 & 1 or what? I don't understand, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

If you perform a binary NOT on a small unsigned integer, you will get a large number as a result, seeing as most of the most significant bits will be set to 1 (the inverse of what they were in the operand).

In this case you're doing `~ 0` which will certainly give you a large number, in fact the largest possible unsigned int, since all bits will be set to 1.

(What result were you expecting?)

Comment: No, because I am inputting a number, it won't be zero. I'm expecting if I input 5 (0101) it will come out as (1010).

Comment: Stil the correct answer. 5 is stored as an `unsigned int`, which means it's at least 0000000000000101

Comment: Well if I was trying for 8bits only, what do I need to change?

Comment: Most reliable way would be to mask the result, ie AND it with 0xFF.

Comment: @Cypras: you said it twice, but your code nowhere specifies that it "works with 8 bits only".